# Include category path in product urls in sitemap and canonical urls

Tags: magento2.3, product-urls, sitemaps, canonical

I am using magento-2.3 EE. I want to include category path in product url, in sitemap urls and same should be in their canonical urls.

Like in sitemap, product urls should be like - `site.com/category1/category2/product-name.html`

Similar structure should be in canonical urls of each product.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below step to do with category path :

**Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" set to "Yes"**

if you want using pragmatically than try with below code :

```
<?php $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
                        <?php     $cats = $_item->getCategoryIds();
                                if(count($cats) ){

                                    if($cats[0]==2){
                                        $firstCategoryId = $cats[1];
                                    }
                                    else{
                                          $firstCategoryId = $cats[0];
                                    }

                            $_category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($firstCategoryId);
                            $categorykey = $_category->getUrlKey();
                            $siteurl= $block->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);      
                            $pro_url=$siteurl.$categorykey."/".$_item->getUrlKey().".html";
                            }
                            else{
                                $pro_url=$block->getProductUrl($_item);
                            }
                     ?>
```

Comment: The above configuration is already set to yes. But still the category paths are not included in product urls in sitemap and canonical urls.

Comment: chanchal did you find any solution  for this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this cannot be done with Magento 2 out-of-the-box. You probably need to use some 3rd party extension.

Magento 2 always generates /product-url.html links as your product can be in multiple categories. So M2 omits the category part in the url.